# 5 second cooldown for user that uses the 'work' command

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a little game setup where players can get/lose money by playing

```
import random
wallet = [0]
bank = [0]

while True:
  action = input('Select Action')

  if action == 'wallet':
    print(f"You have {str(sum(wallet))} 
    in your wallet!")

  elif action == 'work':
    print('You have worked and earned 
    some money')
```

How would you setup a 5 second cooldown (in the most simplest way) to use the command, and a friendly message to inform the user the cooldown hasn't expired yet for work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to just use `time.sleep`

```
import random
import time
wallet = [0]
bank = [0]

while True:
    action = input('Select Action')


    if action == 'wallet':
        print(f"You have {str(sum(wallet))} in your wallet!")

    elif action == 'work':

        print('You have worked and earned some money')

        #Cooldown logic
        print('Starting to cool down')
        print(time.time())
        time.sleep(5)
        print(time.time())
        print('Done cooling down')
```

Sample output

```
Select Actionwork
You have worked and earned some money
Starting to cool down
1557317823.196852
1557317828.1970088
Done cooling down
Select Action
```

You can see there is a 5 second difference between `Starting to cool down` and `Done cooling down` string

Comment: However i would want the user to be able to use other commands while the cooldown is taking place, and bring up a cooldown message when the user tries using the command again when the cooldown hasn't finished.

Comment: In a sense yes.